# Web API attribute validation does not return all errors

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, validationattribute

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project with all controllers decorated with the `[ApiController]` annotation. I use validation annotations like `[Required]`, `[MaxLength]` etc. to validate properties of DTOs received in incoming requests.

Some of my DTOs also implement the `IValidatableObject` interface, to handle more complex validation scenarios not covered by the attributes.

When DTO in the request is invalid because `IValidatableObject.Validate()` returned some `ValidationResult`s, the corresponding validation error messages appear in the response.

But when the DTO ALSO has validation errors because of the attributes, only attribute-related error messages appear in the response.

How can I get all errors to appear?

Here's another, more complex scenario, when not all errors appear in the response. Let's say I have two DTOs - `Parent` and `Child`. `Parent` has property `Children` of type `ICollection<Child>`. `Child` has some validation attributes on its properties. `Parent` has a validation attribute on the `Children` property that checks that the property value, which is a collection, does not contain nulls.

If in the request I send a `Parent` with `Children` collection containing two items - an invalid `Child` and a null, the response has only one error message, the one about the invalid child. If I make the child valid, then the message about null in the `Children` collection starts coming up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show error message together, You can custom validation attribute with `ValidationAttribute` instead of implement `IValidatableObject`, Here is a simple demo:

```
public class CountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            
            int Count = (int)value;

            if (Count > 3 && Count < 7)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Count is not valid, Please try again");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Parent 
    {
        [Range(1,5)]
        public int MaxCount { get; set; }

        [Count]
        public int Count { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Now if the request model is invalid, It will response all the error message.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Xinran Shen. Yes I have a few custom attributes and they do work as intended. But I also have some complex validation scenarios spanning several DTO properties, where adding an attribute to any one of those properties would not make sense.

Also your answer does not cover my second example with two DTOs.

Comment: Your some complex validation scenarios can't be achieved by `ValidationAttribute`? Unfortunately, I don't find any articles about why `IValidatableObject` doesn't show error message with built-in attribute . Maybe You can post a issue in asp.net core github and microsoft developer will explain it.